# Is there a "special" way to identify a default value for a method parameter in IntelliSense via XML comments?

Tags: vb.net, documentation, intellisense, overloading

As is common, I have a series of overloaded methods that all funnel into a single "master" method.  Each of the overloads accepts a different combination of parameters and then passes those values on to the "master" along with some "default" values for anything that wasn't included in the overloaded version.  I'm attempting to create the XML documentation for these methods, and I would like to indicate in some obvious way what these default values are.

Is there a particular XML tag that can be used by this form of documentation to identify default values that will be passed on to another method?  I'd ideally like to see something in IntelliSense that displays something like ***`Default: <parametername> value <defaultvalue>`***, although that may be a bit much to ask for within the standard behavior of the XML documentation features.

If there's no "special" XML tag to use for something like that, I suppose I'll simply need to come up with some appropriate verbiage in the `<summary>` or `<remarks>` section. Something to the effect of ***`"This will use the default value of <defaultvalue> for <parametername>..."`***.  I just think it would *look* better if there were a way to identify these defaults along with the other parameters.

Obviously, this is not a critical need.  I'm simply curious at this point and would like to know if I've just overlooked something.  Here is a sample of the code in question.  I've cut out the actual operational code in the master method as it's irrelevant to this question, but I'll point you to it if anyone needs/wants it.

### "Master" Method

```
''' <summary>
''' Merges multiple PDF files into a single PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PDFFiles">A list of specific PDF files to merge</param>
''' <param name="OutputFileName">The PDF file to create from the merged PDF files</param>
''' <param name="OverwriteExistingPDF">If the specified PDF file already exists, identifies whether or not to overwrite the existing file</param>
''' <param name="SortOrder">Identifies the order in which to add the source PDF files to the output file</param>
''' <returns>A FileInfo object representing the merged PDF if successful. <cref>Nothing</cref> if unsuccessful.</returns>
''' <remarks>Using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>False</c>) may result in larger files, 
''' while using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>True</c>) may result in longer processing times.</remarks>
Public Overloads Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal UseSmartMerge As Boolean, ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal OverwriteExistingPDF As Boolean, ByVal SortOrder As PDFMergeSortOrder) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim ResultFile As System.IO.FileInfo = Nothing
    ...<merge the files>...
    Return ResultFile
End Function
```

### Overloading Methods

```
''' <summary>
''' Merges multiple PDF files into a single PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PDFFiles">A list of specific PDF files to merge</param>
''' <param name="OutputFileName">The PDF file to create from the merged PDF files</param>
''' <param name="OverwriteExistingPDF">If the specified PDF file already exists, identifies whether or not to overwrite the existing file</param>
''' <returns>A FileInfo object representing the merged PDF if successful. <cref>Nothing</cref> if unsuccessful.</returns>
Public Overloads Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal OverwriteExistingPDF As Boolean) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Return Merge(PDFFiles, False, OutputFileName, False, PDFMergeSortOrder.Original)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Merges multiple PDF files into a single PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PDFFiles">A list of specific PDF files to merge</param>
''' <param name="UseSmartMerge">Identifies whether to use a regular <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy"/> or the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy"/> for merging</param>
''' <param name="OutputFileName">The PDF file to create from the merged PDF files</param>
''' <param name="OverwriteExistingPDF">If the specified PDF file already exists, identifies whether or not to overwrite the existing file</param>
''' <returns>A FileInfo object representing the merged PDF if successful. <cref>Nothing</cref> if unsuccessful.</returns>
''' <remarks>Using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>False</c>) may result in larger files, 
''' while using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>True</c>) may result in longer processing times.</remarks>
Public Overloads Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal UseSmartMerge As Boolean, ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal OverwriteExistingPDF As Boolean) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Return Merge(PDFFiles, UseSmartMerge, OutputFileName, False, PDFMergeSortOrder.Original)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Merges multiple PDF files into a single PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PDFFiles">A list of specific PDF files to merge</param>
''' <param name="OutputFileName">The PDF file to create from the merged PDF files</param>
''' <param name="SortOrder">Identifies the order in which to add the source PDF files to the output file</param>
''' <returns>A FileInfo object representing the merged PDF if successful. <cref>Nothing</cref> if unsuccessful.</returns>
Public Overloads Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal SortOrder As PDFMergeSortOrder) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Return Merge(PDFFiles, False, OutputFileName, False, SortOrder)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Merges multiple PDF files into a single PDF file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PDFFiles">A list of specific PDF files to merge</param>
''' <param name="UseSmartMerge">Identifies whether to use a regular <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy"/> or the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy"/> for merging</param>
''' <param name="OutputFileName">The PDF file to create from the merged PDF files</param>
''' <param name="SortOrder">Identifies the order in which to add the source PDF files to the output file</param>
''' <returns>A FileInfo object representing the merged PDF if successful. <cref>Nothing</cref> if unsuccessful.</returns>
''' <remarks>Using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>False</c>) may result in larger files, 
''' while using the <see cref="iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy"/> (<paramref name="UseSmartMerge"/> = <c>True</c>) may result in longer processing times.</remarks>
Public Overloads Function Merge(ByVal PDFFiles As List(Of System.IO.FileInfo), ByVal UseSmartMerge As Boolean, ByVal OutputFileName As String, ByVal SortOrder As PDFMergeSortOrder) As System.IO.FileInfo
    Return Merge(PDFFiles, UseSmartMerge, OutputFileName, False, SortOrder)
End Function
#End Region
```

Comment: Do you have a philosophical aversion to optional parameters?  You could easily move `OutputFileName ` to be the second parameter in your _main_ method and make all the other parameters optional with a defined default. IMHO, that would be a lot cleaner and a lot less code to maintain.

Comment: @TnTinMn - I don't *personally* have an aversion to using optional parameters, but I've been told by other programmers over the years that using them is frowned upon (even though IMO if the language allows it, there's no reason *not* to use them).  Since then I've started writing override methods to get the same effect.  In this case, there are also other overriding methods in the full class code which I can't simply re-order the parameters or I'd have duplicate signatures.  Otherwise, your suggestion *could* provide something like what I'm *looking* for, if not exactly what I'm *asking* for.

Comment: Although, if I understand your comment correctly, you're suggesting the elimination of most, if not all of the overloading methods. In that case, it may be possible to achieve the appropriate method signatures with optional parameters. It would be a lot less code, for certain, but it would take away some of the "ease-of-use" I've been able to implement through overloading.

Comment: "I can't simply re-order the parameters or I'd have duplicate signatures" - My point was that you would have only one signature with the optional parameters.  As far as other's opinion, I'd question if that was not a case of _my_ preferred language did not support them at that time so they must be bad.

Comment: LOL, overlapping comments, I do not see the ease of use issue.  One signature with Intellisense providing guidance and all you need to do is type a comma to use the default or you use the named parameter syntax instead.  I'd take that over a handful of overloads to scroll through.  To each their own.

Comment: *"my preferred language did not support them at that time so they must be bad."* - Many of the people I've worked with and relied on as "mentors" over the years have used Java (and other C-like languages), so that's certainly a possibility. >>> *"To each their own."* - I kinda like the overloads for when the object is being instantiated in a production environment, and `("something", , ,)` does "look" a little funny IMO, but it's not as if I haven't used 3rd-party classes that rely on that style.

Comment: "("something", , ,) does "look" a little funny," - then use this syntax, `Merge(lstFileInfo, "outputpath", OverwriteExistingPDF:=True)`.   Again,  TETO.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever it comes to properties, its a no brainer. My suggestion would be to extend the [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/value) tag to something along these lines:

```
''' <summary>Returns the number of times Counter was called.</summary>
''' <value>Default: 0</value>
''' <returns><see cref="Integer"/> value based on the number of times Counter was called.</returns>
Public Property Counter As Integer
```

However, when it comes to methods (which is what you originally asked), then I'd go with your gut and include it in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/remarks) tag or [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/returns).